# List of list , with predicat filter on parent list and another predicat filter on son list

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I am looking to filter a list according to a predicate and also to filter her child list

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;  

class Hotel {
    private final String city;
    private final int numberOfStart;
    private final List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getCity(){return city;}
    public int  getNumberOfStart(){return numberOfStart;}
    public List<Room> getRooms(){return rooms;}
    public Hotel(String city, int numberOfStart) {
        this.city = city;
        this.numberOfStart = numberOfStart;
    }

    public void creatRooms(String roomNumber ,int numberOfbed,Double price)   {
        Room room = new Room(roomNumber,numberOfbed,price);
        this.rooms.add(room);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Hotel{\n\t" +
                "city='" + city + '\'' +
                ", numberOfStart=" + numberOfStart +
                ", \n\trooms=" + rooms +
                "}\n\n";
    }
}

class Room {
    private final double price;
    private final int numberOfBed;
    private final String roomNumber;

    Room (String roomNumber,int numberOfBed, Double price){
        this.price=price;
        this.roomNumber=roomNumber;
        this.numberOfBed=numberOfBed;

    }

    public double getPrice() {return price;}
    public int getNumberOfBed(){return numberOfBed;}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n\t\tRoom{" +
                "price=" + price +'\'' +
                ", numberOfBed=" + numberOfBed +
                ", roomNumber='" + roomNumber +
                '}';
    }
}

public class Main  {

    /**
     * @param hotelList List search on a list of hotels.
     * @param city relates to the location of the hotel, if empty "", then the predicate will be true, and ignore the city parameter.
     * @param start concerns the quality of the hotel, if set to 0 then the predicate will be true, and ignore the start parameter.
     * @param priceMax
     * @param nbBed concerns the amount beds, ignored if set to 0
     * @return
     */
    public static List<Hotel> searchHotelRoom(List<Hotel> hotelList, String city, int start, Double priceMax, int nbBed) {

        //condition about city location and price on hotel list
        Predicate<Hotel> byCity = !city.isEmpty()? hotel -> hotel.getCity().equalsIgnoreCase(city) : hotel -> true;
        Predicate<Hotel> byStart =!(start==0)? hotel -> hotel.getNumberOfStart() == start:hotel -> true;

        //condition on room list
        Predicate<Room> byNbBed =!(nbBed==0)? room  -> (room.getNumberOfBed()== nbBed) :room -> false;
        Predicate<Room> byPrice = room ->  room.getPrice()<=priceMax;

        return hotelList.stream()
                .filter(byStart)
                .filter(byCity)
                .filter(room -> room.getRooms().stream().anyMatch(byPrice))
                .filter(room -> room.getRooms().stream().anyMatch(byNbBed))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Hotel> hotelList = new ArrayList<>();

        //Dummy hotel data
        Hotel hotelA = new Hotel("Paris",4);
        hotelA.creatRooms("p12", 2, 150.);
        hotelA.creatRooms("p17", 1, 200.);
        hotelA.creatRooms("p15", 3, 50.);
        hotelList.add(hotelA);

        Hotel hotelB = new Hotel("Montpellier",4);
        hotelB.creatRooms("b12", 2, 20.);
        hotelB.creatRooms("b17", 1, 200.);
        hotelB.creatRooms("b15", 1, 40.);
        hotelB.creatRooms("b15", 1, 1.);
        hotelList.add(hotelB);

        Hotel hotelC = new Hotel("Toulouse",4);
        hotelC.creatRooms("c12", 21, 200.);
        hotelC.creatRooms("c17", 11, 100.);
        hotelC.creatRooms("c15", 21, 50.);
        hotelC.creatRooms("c16", 30, 25.);
        hotelList.add(hotelC);

        //System.out.println("Hotels List\n");
        //hotelList.forEach(System.out::println);

        List<Hotel> result= searchHotelRoom(hotelList,"",0,200.,2);
        System.out.println("Result of search");
        result.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

The search function does not work as i would like there is some inconsistency
for example for

```java
List<Hotel> result= searchHotelRoom(hotelList,"paris",0,200.,1);
```

i have this result

```
Result of search
Hotel{
    city='Paris', numberOfStart=4, 
    rooms=[
        Room{price=150.0', numberOfBed=2, roomNumber='p12}, 
        Room{price=200.0', numberOfBed=1, roomNumber='p17}, 
        Room{price=50.0', numberOfBed=3, roomNumber='p15}]}
```

but i want something like

```
Result of search
Hotel{
    city='Paris', numberOfStart=4, 
    rooms=[
            Room{price=200.0', numberOfBed=1, roomNumber='p17}}
```

and it seems that I have no **and logic** between the filters

```java
List<Hotel> result= searchHotelRoom(hotelList,"paris",0,200.,2);
```

must return nohing , but i have a result

And on many hotel

```java
List<Hotel> result= searchHotelRoom(hotelList,"",0,200.,1);
```

I have

```
Result of search
Hotel{
    city='Paris', numberOfStart=4, 
    rooms=[
        Room{price=150.0', numberOfBed=2, roomNumber='p12}, 
        Room{price=200.0', numberOfBed=1, roomNumber='p17}, 
        Room{price=50.0', numberOfBed=3, roomNumber='p15}]}


Hotel{
    city='Montpellier', numberOfStart=4, 
    rooms=[
        
        Room{price=200.0', numberOfBed=1, roomNumber='b17},
```

but i looking for something like

```
Result of search
Hotel{
    city='Paris', numberOfStart=4, 
    rooms=[
        Room{price=200.0', numberOfBed=1, roomNumber='p17} 
}


Hotel{
    city='Montpellier', numberOfStart=4, 
    rooms=[
    
        Room{price=200.0', numberOfBed=1, roomNumber='b17} 
}
```

in search method anyMatch return a boolean but i want list of room,
so i have trie somme stuff on my searh methode like , but doesn't work

```java
 .filter(room -> room.getRooms().stream().filter(byPrice))
```

Does anyone have a clue to help me please?

Comment: I'll dig into this more, but at a glance, in the future you should put some focus into the "minimal" part of "minimal reproducible example" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed recommendation from @alexander-ivanchenko
If it can be useful to someone

To keep the relationship between the room and the hotel
with these changes and additions
I was inspired by this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56080664/java-bidirectional-object-references-using-this-in-constructor)

```
class Hotel {
    private String city;
    private  int numberOfStart;
    private List<Room> rooms ;
    
    public Hotel(String city, int numberOfStart,List<Room> rooms) {
        
       rooms.forEach(s->s.setRefHotel(this))
        this.city = city;
        this.numberOfStart = numberOfStart;
    }
}


class Room  {
    private Hotel refHotel;

    public void setRefHotel(Hotel refHotel) {
        this.refHotel = refHotel;
    }

    public Hotel getRefHotel() {
        return refHotel;
    }

}
```

finally the search function looks like this

```java
public static List<Room> searchHotelRoom(List<Room> rooms, String city, int start, Double priceMax, int nbBed) {
//condition about city location and price on hotel list
        Predicate<Room> byCity = !city.isEmpty()? hotel -> hotel.getRefHotel().getCity().equalsIgnoreCase(city) : hotel -> true;
        Predicate<Room> byStart =!(start==0)? hotel -> hotel.getRefHotel().getNumberOfStart() == start:hotel -> true;

        //condition on room list
        Predicate<Room> byNbBed =!(nbBed==0)? room -> room.getNumberOfBed() == nbBed:room -> true;
        Predicate<Room> byPrice = room ->  room.getPrice()<=priceMax;

       return rooms.stream()
                .filter(byStart.and(byCity))
                .filter(byPrice.and(byNbBed))
                .toList();
    }
```

And in main function

```java
//Dummy hotel data
        List<Room> roomsA = new ArrayList<>();
        roomsA.add(new Room("p12", 2, 150.));
        roomsA.add(new Room("p12", 2, 150.));
        roomsA.add(new Room("p17", 1, 200.));
        roomsA.add(new Room("p15", 3, 50.));
        Hotel hotelA =  new Hotel("Paris",4,roomsA);

        List<Room> roomsB = new ArrayList<>();
        roomsB.add(new Room("m12", 2, 150.));
        roomsB.add(new Room("m12", 2, 150.));
        roomsB.add(new Room("m17", 1, 200.));
        roomsB.add(new Room("m15", 3, 50.));
        Hotel hotelB=  new Hotel("Montpellier",4,roomsB);

        List<Room> roomsC = new ArrayList<>();
        roomsC.add(new Room("c12", 21, 200.));
        roomsC.add(new Room("c17", 11, 100.));
        roomsC.add(new Room("c15", 21, 50.));
        roomsC.add(new Room("c16", 30, 25.));
         Hotel hotelC = new Hotel("Toulouse",4,roomsC);

        List<Room> allRooms = new ArrayList<>();
        Stream.of(roomsA, roomsB,roomsC).forEach(allRooms::addAll);

      /*the result concerns
        *   roomsB.add(new Room("m12", 2, 150.));
        *   roomsB.add(new Room("m12", 2, 150.));
        *   roomsB.add(new Room("m12", 2, 150.));
        *   roomsB.add(new Room("m12", 2, 150.));
        *
        *    * */
        System.out.println("Result of search");
        List<Room> result =  searchHotelRoom(allRooms,"",4,150.,2);
        result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

I have this

```
Result of search

Room{
    price=150.0, numberOfBed=2, roomNumber='p12', 
refHotel
    Hotel{city='Paris', numberOfStart=4}
}
...
...
...
Room{
    price=150.0, numberOfBed=2, roomNumber='m12', 
refHotel
    Hotel{city='Montpellier', numberOfStart=4}
}
```

Maybe there's a better way
And of course there better with Jakarta Persistence Relationship Mapping,
But in my case I don't want to use it, it's heavy for what I need

Answer (score 2):

There's a logical flaw in the `searchHotelRoom()` method.

I guess return type should be a `List<Room>` (not a list of `Hotel`). Think about it this way: when need to find a place to stay, you are not going to book the whole hotel, you need a room instead. There's **no need** for `searchHotelRoom()` generate new `Hotel` instances based on the rooms that match the criteria, we need the rooms itself.

You might want to retain the information to which Hotel a certain Room belongs, this problem can be (*and should be*) addressed on the class-design level. For that, you can introduce a property to the `Room` class. For instance: `String hotelName`, or alternatively a room could hold a reference to the instance of `Hotel`, but in such case you need to **be careful** while implementing methods like `toString()` and `hashCode()` because you might end up with infinite recursion.

So, to get a `List` of `Room`s that match the given criteria, you need to apply a hotel-related filter and then transform a stream of hotels `Stream<Hotel>` into a stream of rooms `Stream<Room>`. For that, you can use [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) operation (or Java 16 `mapMulti()`), which is meant to perform *one-to-many* transformation and expects a *function* producing a `Stream` as an argument.

Then a room-related filter, and collect the result.

**Note** that instead of applying `filter()` twice you can chain the predicates using [`Precate.and()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#and(java.util.function.Predicate)) which is an equivalent of the logical AND `&&`.

```
public static List<Room> searchHotelRoom(List<Hotel> hotelList, String city, int start, Double priceMax, int nbBed) {
    
    //condition about city location and price on hotel list
    Predicate<Hotel> byCity = !city.isEmpty()? hotel -> hotel.getCity().equalsIgnoreCase(city) : hotel -> true;
    Predicate<Hotel> byStart = !(start == 0)? hotel -> hotel.getNumberOfStart() == start:hotel -> true;
    
    //condition on room list
    Predicate<Room> byNbBed = !(nbBed == 0)? room  -> (room.getNumberOfBed() == nbBed) :room -> false;
    Predicate<Room> byPrice = room ->  room.getPrice() <= priceMax;
    
    return hotelList.stream()                        // Stream<Hotel>
        .filter(byStart.and(byCity))
        .flatMap(hotel -> hotel.getRooms().stream()) // Stream<Room>
        .filter(byPrice.and(byNbBed))
        .toList(); // for Java 16 or collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

Comment: Hello Alexander Ivanchenko.

Thank you for your reply  ,

In a use case a user can search according to the hotel and the criteria of the room,  

for example I want the list of hotels and their rooms which have a price lower than 50. , regardless of the city and the number of star
for that i need relationship between a Room and a Hotel.
thank you about tips about predicates.and() methode  

I'm going to try @Ben Anderson  's solution 
or certainly review my class model, to do what I want

Comment: @Krysdow *"I want the list of hotels and their rooms which have a price lower than 50."* - this requirement is ambiguous. When you have a list of `Hotel` on your hands, sure you have access to their rooms, but there could be hundreds of rooms in a hotel, and not all of them meet the criteria. Clients need a list of `Room`s that match their requirements. And in a real application it would be useful to retrieve the information about a hotel (location, rating, etc.) from a `Room` object.

Comment: @Krysdow You might find useful visiting a room-booking like booking.com and play with the functionality they offer. Observe and think what might happen under the hood during each interaction. Probably you'll get a different view on your project.

Comment: yes you are right, I will review my model, certainly extend the Room class to Hotel class, to retrieve information about a Hotel  from a Room object.
thank for sugestions

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a map (or flatmap) as well as a filter to do something like this. The rough form will be something like:

```
hotelsList.stream()
    .filter(hotelFilter)
    .flatMap(hotel -> hotel.rooms.stream()
        .filter(roomFilter))
    .collect(whatever)
```

In general, `map` operations take an `A<B>` and a `B -> C` and give you a `A<C>`. Flatmaps take an `A<B>` and a `B -> A<C>` and give you an `A<C>` (for instance, combining lists, but also performing an operation on an `Optional` that might itself return `None` even if the original value existed)

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact that other answers have already suggested how the problem can be solved by modifying the `Room` class (or just returning a `List` of `Room`s), I'd like to suggest a solution that doesn't modify it, whilst maintaining the relationship between a `Room` and a `Hotel`.

For the method `Main#searchHotelRoom`, you could use `Collectors.toMap` and return `Map<Hotel, List<Room>>` which denotes a map of `Hotel`s against a `List` of `Room`s that met the search criteria for that `Hotel`.

Here is an example of how you could achieve this:

```java
return hotelList.stream()
                .filter(byStart)
                .filter(byCity)
                .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(Functions.identity(),
                        hotel -> hotel.getRooms()
                                      .stream()
                                      .filter(byPrice)
                                      .filter(byNbBed)
                                      .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    )
                );
```

Comment: In case it wasn't clear from my answer, I do recommend creating the relationship from `Room` to its parent `Hotel` as other answers suggest. This solution is really only useful if you don't want to edit the `Room` class or you would like all `Hotel`s returned in the map, even if they have no valid `Room`s listed against them.

Comment: If you wish to remove `Hotel`s from the `Map` which don't have any valid rooms, a simple for-loop to remove all entries where the value is an empty `List` will suffice.